# Some confusions about pack expansion in template parameter section

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

[temp.param#15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#15)

> If a template-parameter is a type-parameter with an ellipsis prior to its optional identifier or is a parameter-declaration that declares a parameter pack ([dcl.fct]), then the template-parameter is a template parameter pack. A template parameter pack that is a **parameter-declaration whose type contains one or more unexpanded parameter packs** is a pack expansion. Similarly, a template parameter pack that is a type-parameter with a template-parameter-list containing one or more unexpanded parameter packs is a pack expansion. A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a parameter pack declared in the same template-parameter-list. [ Example:

```
template <class... Types> class Tuple;                // Types is a template type parameter pack
                                                      // but not a pack expansion
template <class T, int... Dims> struct multi_array;   // Dims is a non-type template parameter pack
                                                      // but not a pack expansion
template<class... T> struct value_holder {
  template<T... Values> struct apply { };             // Values is a non-type template parameter pack
                                                      // and a pack expansion
};
template<class... T, T... Values> struct static_array;// error: Values expands template type parameter
                                                      // pack T within the same template parameter list
```

> — end example ]

About the whole paragraph, I have much confusions about it. I will list my confusions in the following.

1. a **parameter-declaration** whose type contains one or more unexpanded parameter packs is a pack expansion.

   About this sentence, How can a parameter-declaration contain more than one type? A `parameter-declaration` either be the form like `T variable` or `T... variable`, the first is a simple parameter-declaration, the second is a parameter pack that can accept more than one arguments of the same type **T**, whatever, they are only permitted to accept arguments of the same type specified by `T`. Does it say type-parameter? it seems to only type-parameter pack can accept more than one difference types. Or anything others? How to read this sentence?
2. a template parameter pack that is a type-parameter with **a template-parameter-list** containing one or more unexpanded parameter packs is a pack expansion.

   Does this sentence refer to a template template-parameter? It seems to only this kind template-parameter can have **template-parameter-list**, Due to:

> template < template-parameter-list > type-parameter-key ...opt  identifier opt

3. According to the whole paragraph, I still can't understand why `Dims` is not a pack expansion but `Values`  is, What can be a pack expansion according to this paragraph?  It seems to nothing implies it would be as the form like `Something ...` or Did I miss that in this sentence?

If I have any misunderstanding. Please correct me.

Comment: fwiw, the standard isn't intended to be a resource for learning c++, this is much more understandable: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: @idclev463035818 oops, thanks. It's indeed an other way to study c++. Howerver, In this question ,the tag is `language-lawyer`, I only want to discuss this sentence with my confusions after read this.

Comment: sorry, didnt want to imply that the question is no good. Eventually what counts is what is written in the standard not in some reference (though cppref is quite in sync)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Never Mind. The quote is cited from the c++17 standard, I'm not sure it's my misunderstanding or a defect in the standard, So, I post a question here to let language-lawyer guru tell me the answers.

Answer (score 3):

> How can a parameter-declaration contain more than one type? A parameter-declaration either be the form like `T variable` or `T... variable`, the first is a simple parameter-declaration, the second is a parameter pack that can accept more than one arguments of the same type `T`, whatever, they are only permitted to accept arguments of the same type specified by `T`.

You are missing the case where `T` is a parameter pack. The example lists this

```
template<class... T> struct value_holder {
  template<T... Values> struct apply { };             // Values is a non-type template parameter pack
                                                      // and a pack expansion
};
```

Here `Values` have different types. We are expanding `T` to define `Values`, so this is a pack expansion. `Values` is the parameter pack, and it's type is `T`

> According to the whole paragraph, I still can't understand why `Dims` is not a pack expansion but `Values` is, What can be a pack expansion according to this paragraph? It seems to nothing implies it would be as the form like `Something ...` or Did I miss that in this sentence?

You need to have a template within a variadic template definition. That's why `value_holder` has an inner struct `apply`, this paragraph is saying you can't do it in *one* template, you need to nest them. From the example

```
template<class... T, T... Values> struct static_array;// error: Values expands template type parameter
                                                      // pack T within the same template parameter list
```

Comment: For the first one, I'm fairly sure you just reiterated what the OP. I think the OP is actually asking "how can a parameter declaration have more than one parameter pack?" and I think what the standard is referring to is something like `template<typename... T> struct holder { template<std::pair<T, T>... Values> apply { }; };` (Is `std::pair` even a literal type? Can't remember. You get the idea.), where one template parameter declaration (`std::pair<T, T>... Values`) contains multiple parameter packs.

Comment: @Caleth a good answers. However I have to say, Is the T  not a type-parameter pack? At least it's not a parameter-declaration.  If I didn't misunderstand, `int... Dims` this is a parameter-declaration and also a parameter pack.

Comment: @jackX the distinction is that `T` in `value_holder::apply` names a parameter pack, whereas `int` in `multi_array` doesn't. `int... Dims` only defines a pack. `T... Values` both defines `Values` *and* expands `T`.

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, It just interpret what is a pack expansion, namely, such as `T...`, However, how to interpret the first question? I still think `T` is a type-parameter, not a `parameter-declaration`.

Comment: @jackX In `template<T... Values> struct apply`, `T` is not a type parameter. It is a type parameter in `template<class... T> struct value_holder`

Comment: @Caleth If I didn't misunderstand. `T...` is neither the case that the first sentence mentioned nor the second. The first sentence say it's a parameter-declaration, the second seems to say template template-parameter.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I agree that. Please interpret my latest comment.

Comment: @jackX You are misunderstanding. "A template parameter pack that is a parameter-declaration whose type contains one or more unexpanded parameter packs is a pack expansion." is what the example `template<T... Values> struct apply` is demonstrating. `Values` is the parameter pack, and it's type is `T`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216707/discussion-between-caleth-and-jack-x).